# Why a new bounty system for SO questions?

Tags: discussion, bounties

I am interested in getting some answers for

- Why a new bounty system for SO
  questions?
- Is it to increase answer rate to unanswered question?
- What is the purpose of opening bounty to other user's questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you already read the related [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/)?

> Why a new bounty system for SO questions?

Becausethe old system was very imperfect and caused a lot of complaints and feature requests.

> Is it to increase answer rate to unanswered question?

I like to view it as the fixing of a system that was partly broken, with beneficial consequences all round.

> What is the purpose of opening bounty to other user's questions?

The main purpose is probably avoiding duplicates: If you had a question you urgently need answered, and it had been asked already, under the old system, you were forced to try and open a duplicate and hope it survives until the 24 hour waiting period was over. Now, you can simply add a bounty to the already existing question.

Comment: Your point about avoiding duplicates is valid, but the solution doesn't address the problem of *new* users wanting to ask the same question.

Comment: @Chris: Would a discussion on how to fix that not make a good question on its own?

Comment: @3chars - Yes it would. I've started writing the question several times and each time scrapped it. I must try again.

Comment: @3chars - finally asked - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54329/what-can-we-do-for-new-users-who-want-to-ask-a-question-thats-already-been-asked