# Upvote mechanism strictly for "I have the same question"

Tags: feature-request, questions, up-votes, anonymous

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add “I have this problem too” flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77725/add-i-have-this-problem-too-flag)

I'd like to see a button strictly for people that have/had the same question. Such questions would gain more weight as time progresses. Hopefully, experts could zero in on those questions. These upvotes would not require changes in reputation (unless you have something like +2 reputation for getting 10 such votes). People that mark questions accordingly could have the option of subscribing to the question.

I don't find the current question upvote specific enough to this purpose. It would also help alleviate the issue of extraneous "I have the same question" type comments.

**I am aware that some members have suggested using the current upvote for this purpose... but I'm thinking in terms of non-members coming in directly from Google.**

Comment: there's the bounty system to get experts to zero in on particular questions http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/164022

Comment: Per your edit, what's wrong with the existing anonymous feedback mechanism? What would change when a user clicks "I have the same question"? Do they see unicorns and rainbows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this idea is completely without merit.  We already have [anonymous feedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98630/anonymous-user-feedback-now-in-testing) that only gets displayed for users that are not logged in.  Maybe that feature could be reworked to simply display a different message if there are no answers posted yet.  So instead of

> Was this post useful to you? [Yes] [No]

if could display

> Do you have the same question? [Yes]

However, I don't think such votes should be used to add reputation to the post.  Maybe we could just display the total "same question" votes for as long as a question stays on the Unanswered list?  There are other types of incentive other than reputation as well.  Maybe a badge could be added for questions that get 100 "same question" votes?  Or maybe the badge should go to the person who finally answers the question.

Answer (score 12):

**Upvote**, by definition, usually means one (1) of two (2) things:

1. I like this question, it is appropriate for this site and I want other users to benifit from it and it's answers.
2. I have the *same question*

Comment: lanaC A nalP A naM Hmmm... its been ages since I've hit SO not logged in. Can non-members use the Question upvote? If so, I'd suggest the tooltip be updated to "good question and/or you have the same question." Also, isn't there a separation between a good question and solution pairing that solved your own problem and an unanswered question that you also have?

Answer (score 2):

As other answerers have pointed out, the whole point of upvoting is showing that you think a quesiton is good, this is usually because:

- You think the question is good, well-researched, on-topic etc. and you want other users to benefit from it.
- You have the same question.

Rewarding users with reputation because of these upvotes makes perfect sense, whether the user upvoted generally because it was a good question or because they have a similar problem. Either way, **it shows that the user wrote a good question**, therefore they should get rep for it.

Complicating the voting system like this would be a really bad idea, especially considering how the current system already covers your issue.