# How can I draw attention to someone else's unanswered question below the bounty rep level?

Tags: support, new-users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can we do for new users who want to ask a question that's already been asked, but hasn't yet got an acceptable answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54329/what-can-we-do-for-new-users-who-want-to-ask-a-question-thats-already-been-asked)

I found an question asked by another user that describes a problem that I'm also having, but there's no answer, and I don't have enough rep to place a bounty on the question.

**How can I "bump" the question so people may take a look at it again and maybe answer the question?** I'm trying to avoid posting a duplicate question.

Comment: Cry into a pillow

Comment: you are not helping random

Comment: I'll give you a +1 since it appears to be relatively well asked and has code and the error.

Comment: @Kate, hence the answer is try to bump it up, or set a bounty?

Comment: @ChrisF, thanks for the link, although the answer of that question is  helpful, though we still dont have a "standard" way to do that unfortunately, we (low-reps) would still be down voted :(

Answer (score 5):

Publicize the question yourself - post links to it on Twitter, Facebook, your blog and so on. You can copy the URL right from your address bar, but if you use the "link" link that is at the bottom of each question, just below the tags, it will have a trackbug in it that could even reward you with a badge if many people come and read the question. If you follow a Sharepoint PowerShell guru on Twitter, you could @ that person saying "@SPPSguru, can you answer this?" with the link. I can't tell you if it will work or not, but it might.

Comment: great suggestion!

Answer (score 4):

Edit it, but don't make it meaningless.  From [Getting attention for unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/152101):

> You can "bump" your thread **by
>   providing status and progress updates
>   resulting from your own continued
>   efforts to answer the question
>   yourself**. I usually do that unless I
>   really hit a dead end with no further
>   clues to follow. Some times I
>   eventually bring about enough
>   understanding to realise the answer,
>   and thus post a resolution to my own
>   problem.

Answer (score 2):

Participate on the site by answering other people's questions and asking good questions, get to 75 rep, and then finally place a bounty on the question. Help some others and then you'll get some help yourself! :)

Comment: i wish that was a piece of cake, but still thanks!

Comment: @shaheer: Rep actually comes pretty quickly when you post answers. 10 rep per upvote means 75 rep will come real fast.

Answer (score -4):

By making an edit to your question, it will be *bumped up* to the front page. Just add an extra line break somewhere and then save it.

### EDIT

shaheer, note that I based my answer by first looking at your question on SO, which looked okay to me (although I am unfamiliar with PowerShell). I agree with the others that you should preferably improve your question with an "edit", if possible, not just bump it up regardless. I should have made that clear.

Comment: meaningless edits are bad. Make a real edit that helps people answer your question - add details, say what you've tried, and so on.

Comment: you mean that i should make a duplicate?

Comment: @Kate, I wanted to answer something like that as well, but after looking at [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226670/i-want-to-add-web-part-in-web-part-zone-using-powershell-script) shaheer was referring to, it seemed pretty okay to me. That's why I recommended a small "bump". In the general case, I agree that "meaningless edits are bad", but there are exceptions to the rule, IMO.

Comment: @shaheer, no, don't make a duplicate, just edit your question with more information. I just retagged your question (nobody will be following [tag:web] or [tag:part] but [tag:webparts] will help) but other details might help someone see your problem.

Comment: @kate, if i have not ASKED the question how will i edit it?

Comment: ah, that's harder. However you can edit others questions when you have enough rep, and can propose edits even sooner. The effect will be the same.

Comment: @shaheer, :) I thought you were talking about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226670/i-want-to-add-web-part-in-web-part-zone-using-powershell-script) question of yours... About what question were _you_ talking?

Comment: @Bart, i dont have any knowledge about web part, and this is not my question, and i was talking about this question of someone else: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016818/mediawiki-page-editing-allowed-by-creator-only-or-with-approval

Comment: that user has same username as me? :o i think the case difference matters in SO, shaheer and Shaheer... ?